# Efficient method for inverting a block tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm, inverse

Is there a better method to invert a large block tridiagonal Hermitian block matrix, other than treating it as a ordinary matrix?

For example:

```
Do[Evaluate@ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]] = 
  ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]

a11 = DiagonalMatrix@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 3];
a22 = DiagonalMatrix@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 3];
a33 = DiagonalMatrix@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 3];
a44 = DiagonalMatrix@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 3];

a12 = a21 = Partition[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 9], 3];
a23 = a32 = Partition[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 9], 3];
a34 = a43 = Partition[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 9], 3];

s = ArrayFlatten[Evaluate@Table[
      ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1,4}]]
```

The elements live in tridiagonal blocks as well as along the diagonal line.

[image]

Comment: If you are solving a linear equation, then you can easily remove the diagonal terms from both side of the equation. Then the block tridiagonal matrix can be inverse block by block.

Comment: The [algorithm for tridiagonal matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) works with blocks too if you pay attention to the order of multiplication (which is not commutative). You can easily write a procedural function that implements it.  

@xslittlegrass -- What? How? The best algorithm for tridiagonal systems requires a forward-backward scheme. You can't just remove the diagonal _from both sides of the equation_ (at least for there is NO diagonal on the other side of the equation!).

Comment: @Federico Yes you are right, there is no easy way to remove the diagonal terms. When I saw this matrix, I was thinking about Shrodinger equation for a system of several energy levels interaction with a linear polarized classical electric field. The matrix is the total Hamiltonian of the the atomic Hamiltonian plus the dipole interaction Hamiltonian. The atom Hamiltonian, ie. the diagonal term will cancel out, only left the tridiagonal blocks come from the dipole coupling of different states.

Comment: Do you really, truly need the inverse? For instance, if you're solving a linear system whose coefficient matrix just happens to be block tridiagonal, then use a sparse solver instead of computing the inverse, which is more often than not much denser than the original matrix...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Basic implementation

Here is a function `BlockTridiagonalSolve` that takes three lists of blocks (`diag`, `lower` and `upper`) and a list of vector *pieces* (`vec`) and solves the corresponding linear system:

```
BlockTridiagonalSolve[diag_?(ArrayQ[#, 3] &), lower_?(ArrayQ[#, 3] &), upper_?(ArrayQ[#, 3] &), vec_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{a, i, n = Length[diag], d = diag, v = vec},
  For[i = 1, i < n, i++,
   a = lower[[i]].Inverse[d[[i]]];
   d[[i + 1]] -= a.upper[[i]];
   v[[i + 1]] -= a.v[[i]]];
  v[[n]] = Inverse[d[[n]]].v[[n]];
  For[i = n - 1, i > 0, i--,
   v[[i]] = Inverse[d[[i]]].(v[[i]] - upper[[i]].v[[i + 1]])];
  v]
```

To see it in action you can use the following piece of code:

```
nBlocks = 50;
blockSize = 10;
diag = DiagonalMatrix /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nBlocks, blockSize}];
lower = RandomReal[1, {nBlocks - 1, blockSize, blockSize}];
upper = RandomReal[-1, {nBlocks - 1, blockSize, blockSize}];
vec = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nBlocks, blockSize}];
trimat = SparseArray[{
    Band[{1, 1}] -> diag,
    Band[{blockSize + 1, 1}] -> lower,
    Band[{1, blockSize + 1}] -> upper}];
bts = BlockTridiagonalSolve[diag, lower, upper, vec];
ls = LinearSolve[trimat, Flatten[vec]];
maxError = Max[Abs[Flatten[bts] - ls]]
```

Note that `BlockTridiagonalSolve` is slower than `LinearSolve` for small inputs, and grows comparable only for large `blockSize` values.

However, the following fact has to be taken into consideration: if you happen to be able to naturally construct the matrices `diag`, `lower`, and `upper` the way `BlockTridiagonalSolve` requires them, then `BlockTridiagonalSolve` may be the way to go, because a **huge amount of time** is spent (i.e. wasted...) contructing `trimat`, which is required to call `LinearSolve`.
You can experience this for example with `nBlocks = 100` and `blockSize = 100`, in which case `trimat = SparseArray[...];` takes roughly 10 seconds on my Intel-i7 PC.

This is an important general observation: the best algorithm may depend on the type of input you are able to provide, because conversion can be time consuming too.

### Considerations

Of course you may try and compile `BlockTridiagonalSolve` or perform other tricks (such as replacing `Inverse` with `LinearSolve` at lines 7 and 9).
Last but not least, you should consider how `BlockTridiagonalSolve` is meant to be used: will you sporadically call it with different matrices, or will you repeatedly call it with the same matrix always? This makes a huge difference, because in the latter case you may want to "precompile" a specific solver as you would do by calling `LinearSolve` with one argument so that it generates a `LinearSolveFunction`.

Comment: I would recommend using `LinearSolve[]` instead of `Inverse`, actually... to use one of the lines of your code as an example, `v[[i]] = LinearSolve[d[[i]], v[[i]] - upper[[i]].v[[i + 1]]]`.

Comment: Actually, I tested both (in the compiled version, to be precise) and the one with `LinearSolve` does not always perform better, depending on the input size. My conjecture is that `LinearSolve` spends a little amount of time to examine the matrix and figure out which algorithm to use

Comment: @Federico Thanks very much for the answer. Sometimes I have zero blocks in place of the upper or lower band, so a inverse  of that block will gives error. Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Note that the algorithm requires only the inversion of blocks on the main diagonal. Anyway, if you have zero blocks in place of the upper or lower band, your matrix is actually block-triangular, so that you need to perform only the forward or the backward part of the algorithm (depending whether the matrix is lower or upper triangular).

Comment: @Federico Thanks, I see you point. Did you use the formula of the Thomas algorithm in the link in your first comment, and change the "times" to "dot" and "divide" to "dot inverse"? I have a difficult time to associate the variables in your code to the variables in that formula. Could you maybe write down the formula used in your code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Federico and also how do you determine the order of the matrix operations? For example, in the link we have formula like $c'_i=\cfrac{c_i}{b_i - c'_{i - 1} a_i}$, when changed to matrix operation, should it be translated to $c_i\cdot(b_i - c'_{i - 1}\cdot a_i)^{-1}$ or
$c_i\cdot(b_i - a_i\cdot c'_{i - 1})^{-1}$ or
$(b_i - c'_{i - 1}\cdot a_i)^{-1}\cdot c_i$ ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't use the formula on Wikipedia precisely because of that. You have to work them out by hand. The reason is that who wrote them deduced them under the assumption of commutativity of multiplication; so you can't know what kind of manipulations he has carried out. Fortunately, the task of recovering the correct formulas is sufficiently easy to be done in under 5 minutes.

Comment: @Federico Hi, what do you mean by compile. As far as I know, both `Inverse` and `LinearSolve` can't be compiled, and if they in a loop as your code, there will be overhead with `MainEvaluate` in each cycle.